# show/hide div with session (php)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, session

I want to hide the div/button on session. like, If session user is "abc" then don't want to show div/button. and if session user is "xyz" then that div/button should be display.

I have tried this:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['usr'] == 'guest'){ ?>
        <input id="estimate" class="btn btn-sm btn-success " type="button" value="Get Estimation" />
<?php } ?>
```

and I have some onclick code on that  tag.

So, it gives me these error:

Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Onclick event i write ajax event:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getsavedatalist.php",
        data: { uid: usrid },
        dataType: "html"
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        msg;
        document.getElementById('listCon').innerHTML = msg ;
    })
    .fail(function() {
        //alert( " error  in json request failed  " );
        alert( alt_getlist_arr );
    })
    .always(function() {

        console.log( "url :  " +  this.url );
    });
```

I have 3 buttons. when session user is "abc" i want to hide 1 button form that 3 buttons. when session user is "xyz" want to show that button.!

Comment: Show the code where you are bind `onclick` event handler

Comment: Add your full code here so we can see the issue.

Comment: Does that error only appear when the button is NOT showing?

Comment: @Satpal check the edit i do on my description.

Comment: @KaushaMehta check edit i do on my description

Comment: How are you binding `Onclick` ?

Comment: @Satpal i used javascript for that, document.getElementById('showlist').onclick = function(){
.....
.....
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that the `session_start();` is added on your first line of your file. Then put the below code.

```
<?php if($_SESSION['usr'] == 'xyz'){
    //Put the buttons which you want to display on when the use is XYZ.
} else {
    //Put the buttons which you want to display on when the use is ABC.
} ?>
```

Comment: thanks..! i have use these code and do some tricks and its working.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind your onclick listener, you need to check if the element exists. You can do this like this:

```
if ( $( "#estimate" ).length ) {
    //Add your onclick here
}
```

The length attribute of the query gives the amount of elements which are returned by the query, if this is 0 (so no element with id `estimate`) it will skip the if.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form" id="xyz" style="display: none;">
<div class="form" id="abc" style="display: none;">
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    if ($_SESSION['usr'] == 'xyz') {
       $showdiv = 'xyz';
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['usr'] == 'abc') {
       $showdiv = 'abc';
    }

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.getElementById('".$showdiv."').style.display = 'block';</script>";
?>
```

Comment: That is really bad practice if it is about confidential information, this way you still serve the content and anyone can make both divs show with the javascript console. If however this does not matter, it is a way yes.

Comment: if it is confidential information you can create the div on the fly by checking the session, without hiding the div elements.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what he is doing, he just gets the error when he tries to attach a click listener to the non-existing div.  (show and hide in the question are the wrong terms and that confused you I think)

Comment: What i understood from his question was he needed to show and hide -->  "I want to hide the div/button on session"

Comment: Check, if that is the case you answer is correct. +1

Comment: @BasvanStein Yes, i want to hide the button when session user is 'abc', but on that button i have called some JavaScript function. that's why it shows me error. are you getting me ?

Comment: @MenukZ yes. I want to hide/show the button when particular session is start.

Comment: @mananvyas you have to create all the div/buttons available by checking the session variable. on that you can add onclick event for the created elements.

eg : if you create div id='abc_div'  then you can only show/hide abc_div